# Powershell closes on executing exe

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run and .exe in C:programfiles(x86)
I can launch it directly from the filepath. If I run in powershell just closes. No feedback.

Running powershell 5.1.17134 Rev 590

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\App\App.exe"

I tried running powershell -NoExit and then start-process but it returns without any feedback.

If I run it on same machine in Powershell 6.1.0 preview - it runs fine. No issue. How can I track down whats causing this to 1) not run 2)close powershell. 
Thanks,

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: I'd recommend to read the complete help for [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1). Then you should try to use the parameters `-Wait -NoNewWindow`

Answer (score 3):

<sup>This answer makes a general point. It doesn't solve your problem, if using `Start-Process` truly crashes the calling PowerShell window.</sup>

---

**If `C:\Program Files (x86)\App\App.exe` is a *console application* that you want to run *in the current console window*, do not use `Start-Process` to invoke it.**

Instead, **invoke it *directly*.**

Given that its path contains spaces and special characters (`(` and `)`), you need to:

- quote it
- invoke it with **`&`**, PowerShell's [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#call-operator-).

```
PS> & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\App\App.exe'
```

Note:

- The use of `&` with a command specified in a quoted string and/or via a variable reference is a syntactic necessity, given that PowerShell has two distinct parsing modes - see [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).

---

Invoking a console application directly:

- ensures its *synchronous* execution

  - That is, control isn't returned to the caller until the application has terminated.
- connects its standard output streams - stdout and stderr - to the equivalent PowerShell streams.

  - That is, you can capture or redirect the application's success output and/or error output, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You have an interactive shell. You spawn this new process - then your shell closes?

Clearly it is terminating its parent process, and clearly `pwsh` is doing something different.

I don't think this is truly a powershell question, it's a windows internals one. The suite of tools to use is Sysinternals. The first thing I'd try - and I'd do this on `cmd`, `powershell` and `pwsh` to establish a basis for comparison - is run Process Monitor with a filter on your app's path. Something in its last actions may prove illuminating. Process Explorer may also be useful.

Are you in a corporate environment? I have agents on my machine that kill processes based on heuristics. That can do things like this.

There may be a workaround based on how you invoke the app;

- try mklement0's suggestion
- try invoking through WMI; this does not provide your powershell  process as a parent process: `Invoke-WmiMethod -Class win32_process -Name create -ArgumentList "PathToApp.exe"`
- try invoking via cmd.exe if you are constrained by what's on your target machines

I do think this is off-topic, though.

Comment: Nicely done. My answer makes a general point about a frequent anti-pattern, but it may not fit the OP's actual problem - I've added a note to point that out.